# php Google spreadsheet API "Request had insufficient authentication scopes"

Tags: php, api, spreadsheet

i have a Problem with the Spreadsheed api and the "scopes".
With these script i want to update Cells on a Sheet.

I do not work with composer ich have just download the package in intereating it. The Token is already there and the error is from these row:

"$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);"

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('oauth-credentials.json');

$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) 
{
      $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);

      echo "<pre>";   
      $service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
      $spreadsheetId = 'xxx';
      $range = 'Tabellenblatt1!A2:E';

        $response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
        $values = $response->getValues();

        if (count($values) == 0) {
          print "No data found.\n";
        } else {
          print "Name, Major:\n";
          foreach ($values as $row) {
            // Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            printf("%s, %s <br>", $row[0], $row[4]);
          }
        }
    } else {
      $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/api/oauth2callback.php';

      header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
    }
?>
```

These Code brings the following Error

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Service_Exception' with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": 403,
    "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request had insufficient authentication scopes.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "forbidden"
      }
    ],
    "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED"
  }
}
```

Comment: Nobody an idea?

Answer (score 1):

You have this scope defined:
`$client->addScope(Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA_READONLY);`

For accessing a spreadsheet value:
`$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);`

You should have:
`$client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);`
or
`$client->addScope(Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS);`

Source:
https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/googlescopes#sheetsv4

Answer (score 1):

You Must Update the scope as @random425 said,

but after that delete the **Token.json**.
that will start the process of verification again what will give you new token with new scope that you have changed to.